# Poor performance shader with pixi.js, and webgl context lost

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, raytracing, pixi.js

I am new to `webgl` and `pixi.js`. I've done this webgl shader with the help of `pixi.js`: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stla/oaku356j/16/).

It works but:

1. It consumes a lot of ressources
2. If I increase the width and the height of the app, for example from 256 to 512, it crashes with a "lost WebGL context" error.

I'm not sure I'm using the best way to create a shader with `pixi.js`. I'm using `PIXI.Filter` for that. I was told that one can create a shader with `PIXI.Mesh`. Is it a better way?

Otherwise, what could I do to improve the performance of this shader? It consists in 250 tori whose union is rendered using a sphere tracing technique. Is this what causes the poor performance?

Comment: It is the number of circles. For each fragment you call the function `getT` which calls the function `f` 100 times. That function then iterates every circle, there are 250 circles in your scene. That means for every empty pixel there are 25000 inner iterations. For an empty view 512 by 512, counting only inner loop multiplications you need  452Billion operations in total, that is two (five in my view) orders too high. You need to find a way to reduce the inner loop count. Particularly empty pixels as they are so expensive but contain nothing.

Comment: Seems like you've been on Stack Oveflow enough to know that just linking to some code off site is off topic. Voting to close. If you want help please follow the rules. Your quesiton needs to be self contained. Put enough code in the question itself that no external links are needed.

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67. I finally used an analytic expression to compute the intersections: [result](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/frames/pixijs_HopfTorus3.html). The only problem with this technique is that I can't do a smooth union.